# How do I set a React ref to another element onMouseEnter?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

Given that I created a ref, I have a list of items.

When I do `onMouseEnter` on an element, I want this ref to point to that element.

How can I achieve this?

I need this ref because I need to display a popup next the element, and CSS won't help since the elements are inside a `ul` and then a `container` with `overflow:hidden`

Comment: What you're describing sounds like it may be better accomplished with a state variable...refs shouldn't have their value changed dynamically after they've been set.  Maybe if you post some code we can take a crack at it for you.

Comment: @SethLutske the popup needs to be next to the element that is currently on hover. I fixed it by changing the ref (passing from parent to children). Then on mouseEnter I set the ref, and onMouseLeave I null it. Then I also pass a setState function for the "node id" so I can get the text that I need based on that ID.
Then I use hoveredNodeRef.current.getBoundingClientRect() and calculate the pop up position